# Sum boolean values in excel

Tags: excel, function, sum, boolean

I have a number of boolean values A3 == T, B3 == F, C3 == T, D4 == T, E4 == F, etc.
Each true (or "T" in this case) is equal to a corresponding value of 2, while false is equal to 0.

Anybody know how I might sum the numerical values of the booleans without having to do anything like replace their original letter representations?

I am aware of the SUMIF function, but I am not sure how it could be applied in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, (Gary's Student)'s help was good, but not exactly what I was looking for.

Here is how I solved it.

```
=SUMIF(D7,"=T",booleanvalue)+SUMIF(E7,"=T",booleanvalue)+SUMIF(F7,"=T",booleanvalue)
```

etc.

with **booleanvalue** being a named constant

Comment: `=COUNTIF(D7:F7,"t")*booleanvalue`

Answer (score 1):

If they are genuine Booleans and if the range is disjoint then this should work:

```
=2*SUM(--A3,--B3,--C3,--D4,--E4)
```

This works because **FALSE** is already **zero.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the COUNTIF function, e.g. COUNTIF(A1:A20,"=TRUE")